# Good practice to show/remove several ten thousand GoogleMarkers?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have to display several ten thousand Markers on a Google Map. No problem so far.

> 1. Each marker has one of four different categories
> 2. I have a filter switch for each category

So for example:

There are 12,000 markers displayed. I deactivate the "show women" switch, so every women-marker should disappear on the map.

**I add each marker to the google_clusterer, and remove it from there as well.**

```
self.remove = function(){
  self.app.marker_clusterer.removeMarker(self.google_marker, false);
  }
```

When i have just a few hundred markers displayed: No problem. But after a few more thousand my browser is either crashing or takes ages to remove the markers.

> Is there a faster way/smoother way of handling large amount of
>   markers? Any good practice?

Comment: I'm already using Clusters. If i zoom at the lowest level (to "see" no clusters), the markers are getting removed much faster. When i zoom out again (seeing the clusters), it takes ages again.

Comment: That is a lot of objects to have in the browsers memory at the same time (as illustrated by the fact that you're browser is crashing). So the simple answer is don't deal with this many JS objects. In line with Phpdna's answer - this has to be implemented on the server.

Answer (score 1):

You can try a server side clustering in php http://www.appelsiini.net/2008/introduction-to-marker-clustering-with-google-maps.